# Rectangular border widths for sizer in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a sizer with a GridBagSizer with a single element in it as follows:

```
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label="click"), border=5, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM)
```

however I dont want a square border, how can I have a separate size i.e. 10 pixel border for wx.LEFT and a 5 pixel border for wx.BOTTOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `wx.BOTTOM` flag in your example and nest that sizer inside of a vertically oriented BoxSizer. When you add it to the BoxSizer, you can give it the `wx.BOTTOM` flag instead. Something like this should work:

```
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label="click"), border=10, flag=wx.LEFT)

main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
main_sizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.BOTTOM, 5)
```

Note that you'll want to set the `main_sizer` as your sizer:

```
self.panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike :) helpful as always!